# Powershell in variable assignment

Tags: powershell, variables

i'm a newbie on powershell and i have come up with the problem in variable assignment:

Below is the script is used to retrieve free space percentage for drive with drivetype equal 3

I can't pass `$line` to line 6 by retrieving the value from the text file but if I do `c:` instead the script works perfectly, what's my mistake?

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_logicalDisk | ? {$_.DriveType -eq '3'} | select deviceid > driveletter.txt

$content = Get-Content driveletter.txt | select-string ':' -simplematch

foreach ($line in $content)

   {

      "line $line"

      $freespace = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_logicalDisk | ? {$_.DeviceID -eq '**$line**'}

      $drive = ($freeSpace.DeviceID).Split("=")

      "Your $drive Free Space Percentage is {0:P2}" -f ($freespace.FreeSpace / $freespace.Size)

   }
```

Answer (score 1):

That can be done a little bit more efficiently i think

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_logicalDisk | Where-Object {$_.DriveType -eq '3'} | ForEach-Object {Write-Host "Your $($_.DeviceID) Free Space Percentage is $($($_.FreeSpace) / $($_.Size))"}
```

The percentages now show up as 0.xx which isn't ideal. Still looking into that.

**Edit:**Your calculation was a bit off and also did some changes on the write host to make it more readable:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_logicalDisk | Where-Object {$_.DriveType -eq '3'} | ForEach-Object {Write-Host ('Your ' + $_.DeviceID + ' Free Space Percentage is ' +  ($_.FreeSpace / ($_.Size / 100)))}
```